# Count the number of rows in SQL using a string as criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the string $niveis with the following values (example):

```
3,8,10
```

Using this string, I need to count the number of rows in table content, where the access matches any of these 3 values.

For example, if table content is:

```
id   access
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    7
5    8
6    9
7    10
8    10
```

Should return 5.

I tried the following query in PHP:

```
$query="SELECT count(id) FROM #__content WHERE access =$niveis";
```

But it isn't working, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IN` keyword

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM #__content
WHERE access IN ($niveis)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_in_set()`:

```
select count(id)
from #__content
where find_in_set(access, $niveis) > 0;
```